# How the Maximally Stable Extremal Region (MSER) formula works in detail?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm so confused right now, because I still don't understand how to find maxVariation, minArea, maxArea, and thresholdDelta value in manual calculation in MSER with this formula :

$$\Psi(R_i^g)=\left(|R_j^{g-\Delta}|-|R_k^{g+\Delta}|\right)/|R_i^{g}|$$

Can anyone tell me how to solve this formula? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You have to give more context, in particular some web references. Something is odd in your formula : the RHS uses indices $j$ and $k$ that one does not find in the LHS ...